# Spectral sequences using tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

I am trying to draw a spectral sequence in LaTeX using tikz. I would like to draw arrows connecting adjacent nodes; I already drew the first one but it doesn't look horizontal. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,arrows}
\newcommand*\Z{\mathds{Z}}
\newcommand*\ZZ{|[draw,circle]| \Z_2}
\newcommand{\athir}[2]{\displaystyle \bigoplus_{\sigma^{#1}\in C_{#1}}K_{#2}        (\mathbb{Z} [G_{\sigma^{#1}}])}

\geometry{lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm}
\parskip= 6pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={minimum width=10ex,
                    minimum height=10ex,
                    outer sep=-5pt},
             column sep=1ex, row sep=1ex,
             text centered,anchor=center]{
    q\strut   &  0 \strut  &  \athir{0}{q}   & \athir{1}{q}    & \cdots & \athir{p}{q} & \cdots  \\
    \vdots&  \vdots   &  \vdots         & \vdots          & \ddots & \vdots       & \cdots \\                   
   1      &  0   &  \athir{0}{1}   & \athir{1}{1}    & \cdots & \athir{p}{1} & \cdots \\
   0      &  0   &  \athir{0}{0}   & \athir{1}{0}    & \cdots & \athir{p}{0} & \cdots \\
  -1      &  0   &  \athir{0}{-1}  & \athir{1}{-1}   & \cdots & \athir{p}{-1}& \cdots \\
  -2      &  0   &  0  &  0  &     &  0  & \cdots \\
  \quad\strut &   -1 &  0  &  1  &  \cdots &  p  &  \strut \\};
    \draw[-stealth] (m-1-3) -- (m-1-2);
\draw[thick] (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-7-1.east) ;
\draw[thick] (m-7-1.north) -- (m-7-7.north east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You would probably be better off to use the spectralsequences package on CTAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options. You can increase the minimum node height, for example

```
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={minimum width=5ex, minimum height=7ex,
             inner sep=3pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north},
             column sep=2ex, row sep=0ex]
```

Alternatively, you can draw the arrow with the following syntax.

```
\draw[-stealth] (m-1-3) -- (m-1-3 |- m-1-2.east);
```

Using the first option I obtained the following picture of this matrix:

[image]

**Addendum:** Complete, slightly improved code (with some manual tweaks for better looks of matrix) based on second suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,matrix}
    \usepackage{dsfont,txfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    %\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amscd,pinlabel,geometry}

\newcommand*\Z{\mathds{Z}}
\newcommand*\ZZ{|[draw,circle]| \Z_2}
\newcommand{\athir}[2]{\displaystyle\bigoplus_{\sigma^{#1}\in C_{#1}}K_{#2}        (\mathbb{Z} [G_{\sigma^{#1}}])}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={minimum width=5ex, minimum height=6ex,
                    text depth=1ex,
                    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                    anchor=base},
             column sep=2ex, row sep=2ex]%
{
q & 0 & \athir{0}{q} & \athir{1}{q} & \cdots & \athir{p}{q} & \cdots \\
    [5ex,between origins]
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots       & \vdots       & \ddots & \vdots       & \cdots \\
    [3ex,between origins]
    1   &   0     & \athir{0}{1} & \athir{1}{1} & \cdots & \athir{p}{1} & \cdots \\
    0   &   0     & \athir{0}{0} & \athir{1}{0} & \cdots & \athir{p}{0} & \cdots \\
   -1   &   0     & \athir{0}{-1}& \athir{1}{-1}& \cdots & \athir{p}{-1}& \cdots \\
    [5ex,between origins]
   -2   &   0     &  0           &  0           &        &  0           & \cdots \\
    [3ex,between origins]
        &  -1     &  0           &  1           & \cdots &  p           & \strut \\
};
\draw[-stealth] (m-1-3) -- (m-1-3 -| m-1-2.east);
%
\draw[thick] (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-7-1.east) ;
\draw[thick] (m-7-1.north) -- ($(m-6-7.east)!0.5!(m-7-7.east)$) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In the matrix are manually sets distances between the first two and last two rows, `struts` are omitted, for node is used smaller `minimum height`, `inner sep` is set to `0pt` and `text depth=1ex` is introduced. Also the anchors of nodes is changed to `anchor=base`. This on one side better align nodes contents, on the other side align of nodes are slightly mismatched. Consequently the coordinates for horizontal line is determined is middle point of last two cells in the last matrix column.  Distance between rows are increased to `2ex`. With this measures the matrix seems to me a bit nicer.